# Arithmetic with algebraic digits

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
A is a three digit number.
D is a number between 1-9,
If you increase the first digit of A by D and decrease the last two digits of A by D, then you have the product of A and D.
Find A

So the three digit number A can be represented as 100a + 10b + 1c and D being a digit.
So I think the equation would be then be 100a+D + 10b - D + c - D = (100a + 10b + 1c) * D.

Is this right…? I am a bit stuck after this point. I think I need to find the values of a, b and c so that I can find A.

So if I were to rearrange the equation, then D would (100a+10b+c)/(100a+10b+c+1). Any suggestions of what I should do next?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: Express $A=100a+10b+c$  What is the result of the process you are asked to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$A\times D =100(a + D)+10(b - D)+(c - D), 0 \leq a + D, b - D, c - D \leq 9$$
$$\implies D(100a + 10b + c) = 100a + 100D + 10b - 10D + c - D$$
$$\implies D = \frac{100a + 10b + c}{100a + 10b + c - 89} = \frac{A}{A - 89}$$

Let $D = 1 \implies \text{no solutions}$
Let $D = 2 \implies A = 178$

Testing $A = 178, D = 2$, you will notice that it fits the desired conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand where I went wrong now. 
When increasing the 1st digit of A by D, it was 100a + 100D and not just 100a + D! It all makes sense now.